# Is this correct demonstration of faulty singleton pattern implementation?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I read about the Singleton Pattern from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/singleton-1577166.html and it has described some common implementation mistakes. I just want to check if these programs I have written do demonstrate their incorrectness.

In the first program, I have created an inherited class and called the protected constructor of the base class. This allows me to create 2 instances of Singleton.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Singleton {
    public static Singleton Instance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new Singleton();
            return _instance;
        }
        return _instance;
    }
    protected Singleton() {}
    private static Singleton _instance = null;
}

class SingletonBasher extends Singleton {
    public SingletonBasher() {

    }
}

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Singleton x = new Singleton();
        Singleton y = SingletonBasher.Instance();
        if(x != y)
            System.out.println("fail!");
    }
}
```

In the second program I have simply created two objects using new operator and this works because the constructor is protected. Had it been private, I would have been forced to use the Instance method which will only allow me to create 1 instance.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Singleton {
    public static Singleton Instance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new Singleton();
            return _instance;
        }
        return _instance;
    }
    private Singleton() {}
    private static Singleton _instance = null;
}


class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Singleton x = Singleton.Instance();
        Singleton y = Singleton.Instance();
        if(x != y)
            System.out.println("fail!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `return _instance;` is redundant and start with small caps in method name :). At some case you might need to use synchronized.

Comment: @Enzokie Without the `return` statement I am getting a compilation error: http://ideone.com/MLXf3E

Comment: Uncomment the other return statement not that one.

Comment: @Enzokie Thanks! Other than that are both the programs and my reasoning correct?

Comment: Have a look at the [ThreadSafeSingleton](http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples)

Answer (score 0):

This Singleton class is good for a Single Threaded Program. If you want this to be run in a multi threaded program. You need to either;

1. Eagerly Initialize the `_instance` variable like below

   private static Singleton _instance = new Singleton();
2. Synchronize the access to `Instance()` with double `_instance == null` checks.

Comment: Yes I read about the correct implementations in the article I have linked in the question. I just want to know if the two programs which I have written correctly demonstrate that this Singleton implementation is incorrect? I am trying to create 2 different instances in each program, but are they really different?